# Passing a byte array to stream and recovering it back

Tags: c#, arrays

I have written a byte array into a memory stream using :

```
string filename = "C://a.jpg";
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
adapter.PublishPhoto(Message.Create(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(str)), new ContentType("text/plain")), "", "");
```

Now I am trying to recover the byte array using

```
var sr = new StreamReader(message.Body.Content); //message.Body.Content refers to the stream that I created.
var str = sr.ReadToEnd();
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
```

But it throws this exception during runtime : The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

What should I do?

Comment: Look at `str` in a debugger and work out what makes it invalid Base64?

Comment: Did you try to compare the base64 `str` from the first code, to `str` in the second code?

Answer (score 0):

The first code sample that you provided does a conversion to base64 *and back* and can therefore be simplified to the following:

```
string filename = "C://a.jpg";
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
adapter.PublishPhoto(Message.Create(new MemoryStream(bytes), new ContentType("text/plain")), "", "");
```

That is, you're passing raw JPEG data in your memory stream and not a base64 encoded version of that data. You mentioned that `message.Body.Content` in the second code sample is the stream containing said raw JPEG data from the first code sample. You can then thus obtain the bytes from it as follows:

```
using (MemoryStream targetStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    message.Body.Content.CopyTo(targetStream);
    byte[] bytes = targetStream.ToArray();
}
```

You probably intended to actually store base64 encoded data in your stream though, in which case your method of recovering the bytes should work. To do so, modify your first sample along the lines of:

```
adapter.PublishPhoto(Message.Create(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)), new ContentType("text/plain")), "", "");
```